# req.body is empty in POST express nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, post, body-parser

Below is my code for HTML form to post data on server side.

HTML Code:

```
<form action="/Device_Data" method="post">
    <select name="deviceSelect" id="deviceSelect" class="selectdevice" type = "text" style="margin-top:1.5%">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Device</option>
        <option value="Device1">Device 1</option>
        <option value="Device2">Device 2</option>
        <option value="Device3">Device 3</option>
        <option value="Device4">Device 4</option>
        <option value="Device5">Device 5</option>
        <option value="Device6">Device 6</option>
        <option value="Device7">Device 7</option>
        <option value="Device8">Device 8</option>
    </select>
    <button id="Import" value="Import" class="button1" type="button" formenctype="text/plain">Import</button>
</form>
```

Server code:

```
var express = require('express');
//require the body-parser nodejs module
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var qs = require('querystring');
var app = express();
// var server = http.createServer(app);

//support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/Device_Data", function (req, res) {

  // result.entries contains entities matching the query
 //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200, req.body);
});
```

Output:

```
{}
Thu, 16 Nov 2017 14:05:13 GMT express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead at server.js:122:7
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

I just want to print the req.body data.

Comment: how do you submit form data ? where is submit button ?

Comment: <button id="Import" value="Import" class="button1" type="button" formenctype="text/plain">Import</button> to submit the data

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, using the syntax `res.send(status, body):` is deprecated.

Change your following code:

```
res.send(200, req.body);
```

To:

```
res.status(200).send(req.body);
```

For more information see: 
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Change `type` of your button to **submit** and remove `formenctype` from this button.

```
 <button id="Import" value="Import" class="button1" type="submit">Import</button>
```

Comment: You are welcome , by the way `res.status(200).send(req.body);` as Boratzan said. And accept my answer as checked xd